# Flutter Go Router Exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I am a beginner with Flutter and I want to implement nested routes using the go Router. However, I am facing an issue with using shell routes.

Currently, I am using a shell route to push a Homepage which has a scaffold with bottom navigation, allowing navigation between the childs.
Now, I need to add a second shell route .After navigating to '/c', this route should push a second scaffold and display it above the other shell routes, without nesting inside them. It should have its own child screens.

```
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _secondShellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [

    ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        builder: (context, state, child) => HomePage(child: child),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              path: '/',
              name: "a",
              parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
              builder: (context, state) {          
              return const FirstPage();  
               }),
          GoRoute(
             path: '/b',
             name: "b",
             parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
             builder: (context, state) {
            return const SecondPage();
            },
         
             ]),

  ShellRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _secondShellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) => MainPage(child: child),
       routes: [
        GoRoute(
         parentNavigatorKey: _secondShellNavigatorKey,
         path: "/c",
         name: "c",
         builder: (context, state) => const ThirdPage(),),
     
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _secondShellNavigatorKey,
          path: "/d",
          name: "d",
          builder: (context, state) => const FourthPage(),      
      )
      ]
      ),   
 ],
);
```

the _secondShellNavigatorKey not working and occurres an error

_AssertionError ('package:go_router/src/route.dart': Failed assertion: line 408 pos 11: 'route.parentNavigatorKey == null ||
route.parentNavigatorKey == navigatorKey': sub-route's parent navigator key must either be null or has the same navigator key as parent's key)